# Connect to SharePoint online from Azure Function and ASP.NET core web application using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, azure, azure-functions

We are developing those 2 components inside our project:-

1. Azure Function which run on daily basis and which read/write to SharePoint Online lists and libraries.
2. ASP.NET core web application which integrate with SharePoint using REST API.

now we are stuck on the following 2 points:-

**Question-1)** how we can authenticate those 2 components?

**Question-2)** In the Azure Function we want to pass the credentials of an admin account, while for the ASP.NET core web application we want to pass the login user credentials when connecting to SharePoint (so if the user tried to create a new SP item from ASP.NET core application, then the user should have the needed permission on the SP list) .

now we found those links which uses 2 different approaches for authentication (one using AZURE AD APP while the other uses username and password)

https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2021/07/07/app-only-authentication-in-sharepoint-online-using-latest-azure-sdk/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authenticate-sharepoint-using-pnp-framework-in-an-azure-functions/

so what are the differences between those 2 approaches? and which one best suites our needs as per the above 2 questions?

Thanks